# useRef returning undefined on children node but works after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I have a `useRef` hook to a custom component that has `"<input>"` nested inside. I am able to access the `<input>` by using

```
textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children[3].children[2]
```

This code returns the component and renders it

```
return (
  <textfield ref={textfieldRef}/>
)
```

This is my output on textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children[3]

[image: Console]

I can access the input div by using textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children[3].children[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARMye.png)

I am trying to change the height of the `input` element using code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children[3].children[2].style = "height: 50px;"
}, [textfieldRef.current]);
```

But I am getting an error as `"Unable to read property children of undefined object"` on the console, if I comment on the above code reload the React page and un-comment the code above it works fine, but as soon as I reload the page, I get the same error again. I think the `useEffect` is trying to find the `children` component before it even renders. So, is there a way to make the above code execute only when the input is rendered successfully?

Why my textfieldRef is having current null but another current with object I want to access, please have a look at image below

[image: textfieldRef]

Comment: **If** statements.

Comment: @caTS if statement is also failing with InputTypeAhead.js:66 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')

Comment: if(textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children){
            textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children[3].children[2].style = "height: 50px;"
        }

Comment: You're supposed to use `if (textfieldRef.current) ...`. You want to check if the ref exists first...

Comment: if `textfield` is a custom component it should be capitalized: `Textfield` no?
second, `textfieldRef.current.shadowRoot.children[3].children[2]` this is a horrible way to access the children, google "train wreck code" to learn more if you want. A better approach will be to custom the inside elements as well and pass the state explicitly between the components that you need using either "useState", "useRef", "useContext" or redux.

Comment: use optional chain operator everywhere you use ref like textFieldRef?.current?.sha....

Comment: @caTS please check the updated question I have added an image of textfieldRef it has current showing null but another current with values I want to access. How do I access it?